# Create and Sell a Wordpress Theme based on a Template under the CC BY License

Tags: cc-by

This website: https://html5up.net/ offers lots of HTML 5 themes using CC BY licenses. Can I create my own Wordpress theme based on these HTML 5 templates and sell on a theme market like https://themeforest.net/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as you give the source theme the required attribution.

Comment: Why the downvote? A simple question only needs a simple answer.